# Svelte , pass data to chartjs from API

Tags: api, chart.js, svelte

Im new to Svelte , im trying to create chart using API data but have problem pass data to chartjs from API

this is my chart.svelte

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

    export let stats;

    let ctx;

    onMount(async () => {
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "bar",
            data: {
                labels: ["red"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "# of Votes",
                        data: stats.temp0,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    },
                ],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="card bg-gradient-info">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100" bind:this={ctx} />
</div>

{#each stats as stat}
    <p>{stat.temp0}</p>
{/each}
```

the data `stats` is showing correctly in html loop (same component):

```
    {#each stats as stat}
    <p>{stat.temp0}</p>
{/each}
```

but not inside the `<script>`

im sure i need to loop first inside the script , but after many tries i have failed

how can i pass the data to `dataset` in chartjs script ?

`stats` API

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61f99f5d377c1357db3452e8",
    "temp0": "55",
    "temp1": "54",
    "updated_at": "2022-02-01 21:00:13"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61f99858377c1357db3452e7",
    "temp0": "55",
    "temp1": "55",
    "updated_at": "2022-02-01 20:30:16"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61f99153377c1357db3452e6",
    "temp0": "62",
    "temp1": "62",
"updated_at": "2022-02-01 19:25:16"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61f98a48377c1357db3452e5",
    "temp0": "57 ",
    "temp1": "55 ",
    "updated_at": "2022-02-01 19:30:16"
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the structure of `stats`? An array with objects and the values you want to display in the chart on the `.temp0` prop?  Maybe you should then pass `stats.map(stat => stat.temp0)` to the chart

Comment: updated question with API structure

Comment: yes, `stats.map(stat => stat.temp0)` was missing , all working now

Answer (score 2):

The chart component needs to be notified of the new data.

This can be achieved using [reactive statements](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive).

```js
let myChart;

$: if (myChart) {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = [stats.temp0]; // update the data
  myChart.update(); // notify chart.js to render the new data
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1048f5a781384de7aa203cc09b41248c?version=3.46.3)

Comment: Bob,  can you give me hint where to add this in m y code, thx

Comment: See the REPL for a code example (the Chart.svelte tab)

Comment: all looks good in my code , following the REPL, but stil nothing on the chart :(
i did `console.log(myChart.data.datasets[0].data);` and got this output 
```
0: {_id: '61f99858377c1357db3452e7', temp0: '55', temp1: '55'}
1: {_id: '61f99153377c1357db3452e6', temp0: '62', temp1: '62'}
2: {_id: '61f98a48377c1357db3452e5', temp0: '57 ', temp1: '55'}
3: {_id: '61f98341377c1357db3452e4', temp0: '60 ', temp1: '59'}```

but no luck to show `temp0` on the chart

Comment: im sure i need to do something with the `stats` data yet before , but completlly dont know what :)

Comment: all working now

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js expects an array for the data field and not a single value, wrapping it with square brackets so it becomes an array with a single item will make it show up

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

    export let stats;

    let ctx;

    onMount(async () => {
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "bar",
            data: {
                labels: ["red"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "# of Votes",
                        data: [stats.temp0],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    },
                ],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="card bg-gradient-info">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100" bind:this={ctx} />
</div>
```

Comment: i did try this with `[]` but no results

Answer (score 0):

### Using onMount is not best pattern

With Svelte we can do better! There is the [use directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action).
Thanks to the great lihautan, where I learned about it. [See playlist!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoKaNN3BjQX3Gl14MBygFf8buPIw9pAeK)

Applying this pattern, the Chart.svelte component would look like this:

```html
Chart.svelte
-------------
<script>    
    import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
    import {setup} from "./options.js" //returns all chart option, incl. data

    export let chartdata;   
            
    function makeChart(ctx, d){     
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, setup(d)); //init the chart
        return {
            update(u){
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data = u;  
                myChart.update()
            },
            destroy(){ myChart.destroy();   }               
        }
    }
</script>

<canvas use:makeChart={chartdata} width="400" height="300" />
```

To make it more readable, the options parameter is put into an extra file.

```js
options.js
----------
export function setup(data){
    
    return  { 
            type: "bar",
            data: {
                labels: ['cpu', 'card'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "# of Votes",
                        data,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
                            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    },
                ],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        };
}
```

In the main app via the input fields, it is possible to dynamically change the values of the displayed data.

```html
App.svelte
----------
<script>
    import Chart from "./Chart.svelte";
    let cpu = 1;    let cards = 2;  
    $: chartdata = [cpu, cards];
</script>

<div>
    <label>cpu <input type="number" bind:value={cpu} /> </label>
    <label>cards <input type="number" bind:value={cards} /> </label>    
</div>

<Chart {chartdata} />

<style>
    div{
         display: flex;
    }
</style>
```

In the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/abe5272f83c641978fa9c8eb7072c0af?version=3.55.1) you may find the working code. Just wait a litte bit, until the chart.js package is loaded.